# Compare two files ignoring order

Tags: bash, unix, diff

I have two files which the order of lines is irrelevant, and I want to compare its content.

I looked into `diff` documentation but could not find anything like `--ignore-order`.

Any tips?

Comment: See my answer at https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/23303/diff-where-lines-are-mostly-the-same-but-out-of-order

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Sort the files first:

```
$ sort file1 > file1.sorted
$ sort file2 | diff - file1.sorted
```

Also, although I personally discourage this sort of thing, if you are using bash and this feature is enabled on your system you can avoid the temporary file by using a process substitution:

```
$ diff <(sort file1) <(sort file2)
```

Answer (score 2):

Not bash, but still fast way using python:

```
def check_diff(file1,file2):
    check = {}
    for file in [file1,file2]:
        with open(file,'r') as f:
            check[file] = []
            for line in f:
                check[file].append(line)
    diff = set(check[file1]) - set(check[file2])
    for line in diff:
        print(line.rstrip())
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you're looking at the problem from the wrong side. Perhaps you would like to sort both files and then compare them?

Otherwise,

```
diff file1 file2
```

would do exactly what you are asking for.