# Compare a list of strings in Bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a list of rpm files in a file called rpmlist.txt which I have to compare with another list, newlist.txt, and see if they are same in Bash. For example, this is my requirement:

files inside rpmlist.txt

```
bash-4.4-9.10.1_x86_64
binutils-2.32-7.8.1_x86_64
bison-3.0.4-1.268_x86_64
```

files inside newlist.txt

```
bash-5.4-9.10.1_x86_64
binutils-2.32-7.8.1_x86_64
bison-6.0.4-1.268_x86_64
```

And print if they are matching or not. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: `diff -y file1 file2`, `comm -12 <(sort file1) <(sort file2)`, `grep -f file1 file2` ...

Comment: does the order of the lines matter?

Comment: No, order can be anything. Just list1 have to check if there is any matching on list2.

Comment: what is list2? can newlist.txt contain files that are not in rpmlist.txt? can rpmlist.txt contain files that are not in newlist.txt?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10708300/compare-two-files-ignoring-order) solve your problem?

Comment: Yes, we cannot expect the the files to contain items. List can vary. Requirement is to just check name in file1 is equal to name in file 2.  IF there;s no matching, ignore it.

Comment: the way you are using words like "equal" is ambiguous. It would help if you add examples of "matching" and "not matching" to your question. `1:abc = 2:abc` ? `1:abc = 2:acb` ? `1:abc = 2:abcd` ? `1:abc = 2:bcd` ? `1:abc = 2:ab` ? etc

Answer (score 2):

Try with:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

# Load files into arrays

readarray source_list < rpmlist.txt
readarray target_list < newlist.txt

# Check files size

source_size=${#source_list[@]}
target_size=${#target_list[@]}

if [ ${source_size} -ne ${target_size} ]; then
    echo "File lines count not matching!" >&2
    exit 1
fi

# Enum files

for (( i=0; i < ${source_size}; i++ )); do

  # Get file name

  source_file=${source_list[$i]}
  target_file=${target_list[$i]}

  # Remove CR/LF

  source_file=$(echo "${source_file}" | sed 's:\r$::')
  target_file=$(echo "${target_file}" | sed 's:\r$::')

  # Check if files exist

  if [ ! -f ${source_file} ] || [ ! -f ${target_file} ]; then
    echo "Source and/or Target does not exist." >&2
    exit 2
  fi

  # Compare files

  diff -q "${source_file}" "${target_file}"

done
```

**PS:** I tested it and it works.

**Edit (1)**

Based on comments, I think you should replace my script with the following simple command:

`cat rpmlist.txt | xargs -I "{}" grep "{}" newlist.txt`

**Edit (2) - Unmatched list**

`cat rpmlist.txt | xargs -I "{}" grep -v "{}" newlist.txt`

Comment: I am getting an error -> File lines count not matching!

Comment: Count will vary @Antonio

Comment: As yo can see, it check that the count of lines in the source files must match with the file count of the target files. Please check it and remove any blank lines.

Comment: Source file lines will always have lesser count. We cant predict as it is package list from OS.

Comment: Ok, but you did not explain this on your post. So I did not guess this detail.

Comment: Sorry Antorio. My bad. So basically there will a list in source file. We have to check if the name  matches in target file.

Comment: So that command gave me a list of names. Just to clarify, the output is the matchings of both the files. right?

Comment: The output is the matching of the file names. Is it right for you? Did you intend this?

Comment: That's correct. Thanks a lot Antonio. I appreciate it. Can you also tell me how to find the unmatched list?

Comment: I edit again the post. Please, then accept it. Regards.

Answer (score 0):

This will cross-compare an arbitrary number of such files.

```sh
#!/bin/bash
set -e

declare -ar list_names=("$@")
declare -Ai "${list_names[@]}"

for list in "${list_names[@]}"; do
  declare -n set="$list"
  while IFS= read -r line; do
    ((++set["$line"]))
  done < "${list}.txt"
done

compare_lists() {
  local -rn set1="$1"
  local -rn set2="$2"
  local name
  echo "Lines in ${1}, but not in ${2}:"
  for name in "${!set1[@]}"; do
    ((set2["${name}"])) || printf '  %s\n' "$name"
  done
}

declare -i idx jdx
for ((idx = 0; idx < ${#list_names[@]}; ++idx)); do
  for ((jdx = idx + 1; jdx < ${#list_names[@]}; ++jdx)); do
    compare_lists "${list_names[idx]}" "${list_names[jdx]}"
    compare_lists "${list_names[jdx]}" "${list_names[idx]}"
  done
done
```

Example (when the above script is called `listdiff.sh`):

```
$ ./listdiff.sh rpmlist newlist
Lines in rpmlist, but not in newlist:
  bison-3.0.4-1.268_x86_64
  bash-4.4-9.10.1_x86_64
Lines in newlist, but not in rpmlist:
  bison-6.0.4-1.268_x86_64
  bash-5.4-9.10.1_x86_64
```

And it can get more arguments than 2.

Comment: Getting an error : ./bash.sh rpmlist newlist
./bash.sh: line 7: rpmlist.txt: No such file or directory
./bash.sh: line 7: newlist.txt: No such file or directory
Lines in rpmlist, but not in newlist:
Lines in newlist, but not in rpmlist: